# Can I retrieve files from Time Capsule if I lost my laptop and want to retrieve the files to my new laptop?

Tags: time-capsule

I want to retrieve files from my recently stolen laptop and it's not showing up. I am using Migration Assistant. I can see the backup for the laptop I am currently using, but I want to see the backup for the missing laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Choose Time Machine from the menu bar, hold alt and select Browse Other Backup Disks, then select your old machine's backups.